# Project selection tab can not find the referenced library

Tags: java, android, jar

I tried to add an external jar file in my app and my system identified this and created the referenced library folder. But in properties>android of my project project selection tab can not find my library.

[image: Image of issue]

Answer (score 0):

When I was using eclipse I went through this. I never found a solution of using jar directly but I followed the following steps to include this library.

To add any library the steps are:

1) Eclipse -> Import -> Existing Android Code into workspace.

2) Add your_sdk_path\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat to your Eclipse workspace.

3) Right click on your project in Eclipse and select properties.(The window you have shown in the pic)

4) Select Android -> Library -> Add.

5) Select the imported project(appcompat) and Save.

I hope this might help. For any query feel free to ask.

Comment: In step 2 i have a problem . android support v7 appcompat is a jar file . when i open the import window based on step 1 and add this jar file path . system can not find any thing .

Comment: No u can't add jar file(I mean u might be but I was not able to, I am giving u another solution which I used). Did u download the Android Support Library? If u don't know follow the path I have mentioned in step 2, if the folders are not like this then u haven't. So to get it, open the SDK manager, and in Extras section the first item will be Android Support Library. Download it and then follow the steps.

Comment: If this answer was the one that solved your problem then don't forget to mark it as correct so that other people can also get help.